# Php Static Page

Tags: php, html, sql

I try to create a user profile page. All visitor can see this page

www.sample.com/details.php?id=1

```
 <?php
            foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM uyeler') as $row) {
                    echo "<tr><td>" .$row['id'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['username'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['sex'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['country'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['age'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['twitter'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['instagram'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['snapchat'] . "</td>";
                    echo ('<td><a href="details.php?id=' .$row['id'] . '" title="Panel">Details</a></td>');
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>
```

When they click this link. Detail page will open.

I try to create details.php with these codes

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
foreach($db->query("SELECT country FROM uyeler WHERE id =' .$row['id'] . '") as $row) 
    echo $row['id'];

?>
```

How can i fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're presumably taking the ID for the query from the $_GET variable, rather than the $row. You should check that it's the right format (i.e. a `if(is_numeric($_GET['id']))` condition before attempting the database query to prevent injection attacks.

You were also selecting the 'country' column and then looking for the 'id'. Try this:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    foreach($db->query("SELECT country FROM uyeler WHERE id =' .$_GET['id'] . '") as $row) 
      echo $row['country'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc() in /home/acamate/public_html/farkc.com/details.php on line 5

Comment: OH - my bad, I (wrongly) assumed you were using mysqli

Comment: :( not fixed

Do i need to write anything here about GET on table
`echo ('<td><a href="details.php?id=' .$row['id'] . '" title="Panel">Details</a></td>');`

Comment: No, that is sending the correct information. Does the $_GET variable pass correctly. When you are seeing the details.php page does the URL have a value after the `?id=` ?

Comment: Try re-writing the query - sorry, returning to PDO I messed up a little and didn't correct the syntax. `"SELECT country FROM uyeler WHERE id =" .$_GET['id']`

Comment: Thank you very much :) but it is very interesting. it works without " at the end